# jQuery is adding styles to every class, when I said not to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set a data attrabute called "sel", and the following jQuery asks for the data-sel that has a value of 'true', but it's adding it to every class, even the ones that don't have 'data-sel'

jQuery:

```
var selTrue = $(".slide").data("sel", 'true');
$(selTrue).css({'display': 'inline-block'});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='slide' data-sel='true'>1</div>

<div class='slide' data-sel='true'>2</div>

<div class='slide'>3</div>

<div class='slide'>4</div>
```

How do I prevent if from applying to to every class?

Trying to solve:

• I tried this:

```
$(".slide").not(selTrue).css({'display': 'none'});
```

still didn't solve my problem

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93M4f/)

Comment: Because of method chaining, `selTrue == $(".slide")`.

Comment: @Barmar, ah i didnt think the data function had the chaining on it.

Comment: All jquery functions that don't need to return something else are chainable. `.data()` with one argument returns the data value, so it can't be chained. But `.data()` with two arguments is chainable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to select against your data attribute you need to use

```
$(".slide[data-sel='true']").css({'display': 'inline-block'});
```

what you're doing is actually selecting all elements with the `slide` class, and then setting their `data-sel` attribute.

here's the documentation

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Oh, wow, very simple fix, can't beleive I got stuck on this.  Anyways, thanks! I'll be sure to vote best (if it works).

Comment: Just to add It would be .slide[data-sel='true'] no?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana and Barmar, yes.

Comment: @user3314062 I should have given you the chance to edit on your own...jumpy edit fingers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".slide").each(function () {
    if ($(this).data("sel") === true) {
        $(this).css({'display': 'inline-block'});
    }
});
```

You are setting the data-sel attribute to true with

```
$(".slide").data("sel", 'true');
```

Comment: it's unnecessary to loop and go through conditionals. it's easy to select against data attributes. see my answer below

Comment: I never liked using attribute selectors. There are a still a few bugs with open tickets.  It probably is faster though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selTrue = $(".slide").data("sel", 'true');
```

What that does is fetch all divs with class "slide" and set the value 'true' for key 'sel' on them. So `selTrue` is a jQuery array of all divs with class `.slide`. And then you are setting `display: inline-block` for all elements in the array (the 4 divs on the page).

What you want to do is :
`$('.slide[data-sel = "true"]').css('display', 'inline-block')`

The square brackets indicate a query based on an attribute.